# Golang exported type

Tags: go

Suppose I have a package within a package `github.com/user/foo`:

```
foo/
  main.go (package main)
  bar/
    bar.go (package bar)
```

Now, within `bar.go` I would like to use an exported type from `main.go`.

```
package main
type FooBar struct {}
```

If I try to `import "github.com/user/foo"` I get cycled imports not allowed error. Is there any way to do this, other than to create own repo for `bar`, which I don't want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can separate it like:

```
foo/
  main.go (package main)
  foo/
    foo.go (package foo)
  bar/
    bar.go (package bar)
```

then `import "path/foo/foo"` in bar.go

Comment: This would require a rather large refactoring for my existing codebase...it would clean things up however.

Comment: @Jan a little bit refactoring doesn't hurt and IMO it will be easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Oh yea I totally agree. It would remove main namespace pollution and modularize the codebase. But, its a large legacy project, so Im going to pass on this refactoring.

Comment: A large legacy project in Go? I didn't realize we were old enough to have legacy projects... My how time flies.

Comment: @synful go is 5 years old, hard to believe.

Comment: Well, yeah, but it wasn't really a stable language until the 1.0 release, which was 2.5 years ago. I doubt there are any existing (maintained) codebases using a pre-1.0 language spec.